# Using DocuSign TemplateReference to wrap InlineTemplate requires doubles the payload?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am attempting to test DocuSign by combining a template on the server and a local PDF document.

The following code works, however, I am afraid that I am sending double the payload on the `InlineTemplate`.

```
public virtual TemplateReference CreateInlineTemplate(Recipient[] recipients, AdHocTemplate adHocTemplate, int sequenceId)
{
  var templateReference = new TemplateReference();
  templateReference.TemplateLocation = TemplateLocationCode.SOAP;

  var inlineTemplate = new InlineTemplate
  {
      Sequence = sequenceId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
      Envelope = new Envelope
      {
          Recipients = recipients, AccountId = _apiAccountId
      }
  };

  var document = new Document
  {
      ID = sequenceId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
      Name = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(adHocTemplate.Name)
                 ? "Contract " + sequenceId
                 : adHocTemplate.Name,
      PDFBytes = adHocTemplate.Bytes,
      FileExtension = ".pdf",
  };

  // added once
  inlineTemplate.Envelope.Documents = new[] { document };

  // added twice. Effectively doubled the size of the message.
  templateReference.Document = document;
  templateReference.Template = SerializeTemplate(inlineTemplate);
  templateReference.RoleAssignments = CreateRoleAssignments(recipients).ToArray();

  return templateReference;
}
```

As you can see I am creating a `Document` with the local file and then providing it to the `InlineTemplate` and the `TemplateReference`. This appears to be the only way to get this to succeed in sending.

If I don't provide the document to the inline-template, I get the error of:

> "Unable to load template. Unable to load template from
>   TemplateReference(1). Error: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object"

Not providing it to the `TemplateReference`, I get an error telling me that the buffer cannot be null.

Attempting to just set empty documents fails because it says the document is incomplete.

**Is there a way to get this to work without sending twice the bytes in the message?**

I looked into doing a `CompositeTemplate` and using `CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms()` to send it, however, I need to pre-fill data on the server templates, and using `ServerTemplate` does not provide a way to add in the custom field data.

Comment: could you please share a code sample on this ? Am trying to achieve what you did, finding it complete confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is possible through *createEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms().*  See page 76 of the SOAP API guide and read the "Rules for Composite Template Usage" section carefully.  The way it all works confused me for a long time.  But basically the templates are all additive so you can include a *Tab* to set your server template field values in any *InlineTemplate* where the *TabLabel* matches the *Label* of the field on your server template.  There's a good example provided in the doc on page 80.  (Search on "From Inline Template")

In my example my server template has a Data Field with *TabLabel* of "MyField"  So this tab gets put into the *InlineTemplate* to set the value.

[image: Date Field on server template]

```
<ns:Tab>
    <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
    <ns:TabLabel>MyField</ns:TabLabel>
    <ns:Value>Value from Inline Template</ns:Value>
    <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
</ns:Tab>
```

I attached the request I ended up with while trying to solve your question.  The remaining issue it has is it seems like a CompositeTemplate can only take one set of documents.  So you need to split into two CompositeTemplates.  But I was definately able to populate my "MyField" server template field.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms>
         <ns:EnvelopeInformation>
            <ns:AccountId>ACCOUNT ID</ns:AccountId>            
         </ns:EnvelopeInformation>
         <ns:CompositeTemplates>
            <ns:CompositeTemplate>
               <ns:ServerTemplates>
                  <ns:ServerTemplate>
                     <ns:Sequence>1</ns:Sequence>
                     <ns:TemplateID>TEMPLATE ID</ns:TemplateID>
                  </ns:ServerTemplate>
               </ns:ServerTemplates>
               <ns:InlineTemplates>
                  <ns:InlineTemplate>
                     <ns:Sequence>2</ns:Sequence>
                     <ns:Envelope>
                        <ns:Asynchronous>false</ns:Asynchronous>
                        <ns:AccountId>ACCOUNT ID</ns:AccountId>
                        <ns:Recipients>
                           <ns:Recipient>
                              <ns:ID>1</ns:ID>
                              <ns:UserName>John Q Signer</ns:UserName>
                              <ns:Email>EMAIL HERE</ns:Email>
                              <ns:Type>Signer</ns:Type>
                              <ns:RoleName>Signer1</ns:RoleName>
                              <ns:RoutingOrder>1</ns:RoutingOrder>
                           </ns:Recipient>
                        </ns:Recipients>

                        <ns:Documents>      
                           <ns:Document>
                              <ns:ID>1</ns:ID>
                              <ns:Name>Inline Document</ns:Name>
                              <ns:PDFBytes>PDF BYTES HERE</ns:PDFBytes>
                              <ns:TransformPdfFields>false</ns:TransformPdfFields>
                           </ns:Document>
                        </ns:Documents>

                        <ns:Tabs>
                           <ns:Tab>
                            <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
                            <ns:TabLabel>MyField</ns:TabLabel>
                            <ns:Value>Updated by Inline Template</ns:Value>
                            <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                        </ns:Tab>

                           <ns:Tab>
                              <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
                              <ns:AnchorTabItem>
                                 <ns:AnchorTabString>{{s1_sign}}</ns:AnchorTabString>
                                 <ns:XOffset>0</ns:XOffset>
                                 <ns:YOffset>0</ns:YOffset>
                                 <ns:IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</ns:IgnoreIfNotPresent>
                              </ns:AnchorTabItem>                             
                              <ns:Type>SignHere</ns:Type>
                           </ns:Tab>
                           <ns:Tab>
                              <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
                              <ns:AnchorTabItem>
                                 <ns:AnchorTabString>{{s1_initial}}</ns:AnchorTabString>
                                 <ns:XOffset>0</ns:XOffset>
                                 <ns:YOffset>0</ns:YOffset>
                                 <ns:IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</ns:IgnoreIfNotPresent>
                              </ns:AnchorTabItem>                             
                              <ns:Type>InitialHere</ns:Type>
                           </ns:Tab>
                        </ns:Tabs>

                        <ns:Subject>Composite Test</ns:Subject>
                        <ns:EmailBlurb>Composite Test</ns:EmailBlurb>
                        <ns:SigningLocation>Online</ns:SigningLocation>
                          <ns:AutoNavigation>false</ns:AutoNavigation>
                          <ns:EnvelopeIdStamping>false</ns:EnvelopeIdStamping>
                          <ns:AuthoritativeCopy>false</ns:AuthoritativeCopy>
                        <ns:Notification>
                           <ns:UseAccountDefaults>false</ns:UseAccountDefaults>
                           <ns:Reminders>
                              <ns:ReminderEnabled>false</ns:ReminderEnabled>
                              <ns:ReminderDelay>1</ns:ReminderDelay>
                              <ns:ReminderFrequency>1</ns:ReminderFrequency>
                           </ns:Reminders>
                           <ns:Expirations>
                              <ns:ExpireEnabled>true</ns:ExpireEnabled>
                              <ns:ExpireAfter>2</ns:ExpireAfter>
                              <ns:ExpireWarn>1</ns:ExpireWarn>
                           </ns:Expirations>
                        </ns:Notification>                        
                        <ns:EnforceSignerVisibility>true</ns:EnforceSignerVisibility>
                        <ns:EnableWetSign>false</ns:EnableWetSign>
                        <ns:AllowMarkup>false</ns:AllowMarkup>
                        <ns:AllowReassign>false</ns:AllowReassign>
                        <ns:BrandId>BRAND ID</ns:BrandId>
                        <ns:BrandLock>true</ns:BrandLock>
                        <ns:MessageLock>true</ns:MessageLock>
                        <ns:RecipientsLock>true</ns:RecipientsLock>
                     </ns:Envelope>
                  </ns:InlineTemplate>
               </ns:InlineTemplates>               
            </ns:CompositeTemplate>
         </ns:CompositeTemplates>
         <ns:ActivateEnvelope>true</ns:ActivateEnvelope>
      </ns:CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: So the server templates will read the tabs from the inline template to fill their own fields? I will have to test this out Monday as we just recently found we had to call `createEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms` for another purpose.

Comment: Yes.  The idea is you don't need entire Envelopes in each template, they can be partial like just defining Recipients.  It takes the elements from each template and combines it into one giant envelope by using an order of precedence.  Having three plus different places to define some things can get confusing though, trying to figure out where they should go.

Comment: Such great info. Will try this tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Not 100% sure. It answers my actual question by using composite template instead, but have not been able to get prefill yet (Haven't had time). Had to award the bounty or it would have been lost, but I believe other than prefill is working. Thanks.